# Jira Rest API: Requesting issue(s) of a specific user in one or more projects (Beginner)

Tags: rest, api, get, jira, soapui

For testing and practice purposes I want to create a specific request in Jira by using its REST api:

I want to list all issues from a specific user in one or more specific projects.

I tried it with SOAP UI but I was not able to create or get my results with easy GET-HTTP requests (I don't know how to combine more values and parameter together). The other way would be to use a script language but here I don't know what to use.

The documentation is somewhat confusing for a beginner like me and I would like to know how combine different values and paramter and how to start in an easy way.

Comment: Would you mind showing how or what you tried and the issue being faced?

Comment: One of my bosses, who thought it would be an easy task, invested some hours into this and gave me a basic construction to start with. I will post it as answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use advance rest client for chrome browsers to make your Rest requests.
The examples below (from official documentation) are for Curl usage but its simple to pass them to advance rest client. Dont forget the authentication.

Link to [advance rest client](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-1r6BsIDTAhXE6RQKHZ02AoQQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fadvanced-rest-client%2Fhgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo&usg=AFQjCNEo489FdO7M0eVz4c9u475vROBbXQ&sig2=5tI1b2Mxud6q7Mud1-vdcw)

Example of create issue:

Request

```
 curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data {see below} -H "Content-Type:  application/json" http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/
```

Data

```
{
  "fields": {
     "project":
     { 
        "key": "TEST"
     },
     "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
     "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
     "issuetype": {
        "name": "Bug"
     }
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
 "id":"39000",
 "key":"TEST-101",
  "self":"http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/39000"
}
```

Example of making a query issue:

Request:

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=fred
```

Response:

```
{
"expand": "schema,names",
"startAt": 0,
"maxResults": 50,
"total": 6,
"issues": [
    {
        "expand": "html",
        "id": "10230",
        "self": "http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/BULK-62",
        "key": "BULK-62",
        "fields": {
            "summary": "testing",
            "timetracking": null,
            "issuetype": {
                "self": "http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issuetype/5",
                "id": "5",
                "description": "The sub-task of the issue",
                "iconUrl": "http://kelpie9:8081/images/icons/issue_subtask.gif",
                "name": "Sub-task",
                "subtask": true
            },
            },
            "customfield_10071": null
        },
        "transitions": "http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/BULK-62/transitions",
    },
    {
        "expand": "html",
        "id": "10004",
        "self": "http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/BULK-47",
        "key": "BULK-47",
        "fields": {
            "summary": "Cheese v1 2.0 issue",
            "timetracking": null,
            "issuetype": {
                "self": "http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issuetype/3",
                "id": "3",
                "description": "A task that needs to be done.",
                "iconUrl": "http://kelpie9:8081/images/icons/task.gif",
                "name": "Task",
                "subtask": false
            },

              "transitions": "http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/BULK-47/transitions",
    }
 ]
}
```